# CodeIgniter password not validating against database

Tags: codeigniter, passwords

I've setup my login functions in CodeIgniter (email/password). The email field is validating properly against the database, but as long as the email is validated any password is accepted--even blank passwords.

I need to figure out why only the email field is being checked against the database and how to get the password field to validate against the database.

Sidebar: I'm planning to encrypt the passwords next, but want to be sure the field is validating against the database first. Then I'll add the security layers.

**From the login controller:**

```
 function login_validation()

{
    $this->load->model('foo_model');
    $query = $this->foo_model->validate();

    if($query) 
    {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('foodash');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index(); // login page
    }
}
```

**From the foo model:**

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));

    $query = $this->db->get('footable');

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }           
}
```

}

**FIGURED IT OUT:**
I was masking my password field using jquery so that the text wasn't visible when entered. I had to change the name of my password field--once I changed it in the model, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIGURED IT OUT:**

I was masking my password field using jquery so that the text wasn't visible when entered. I had to change the name of my password field--once I changed it in the model, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `false` in your `validate()` function after your `IF` statement.

Also try a different syntax:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('footable', array(
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
));
```

Comment: No change using this syntax or using false after the IF statement. Still can login with no password or any password.

Answer (score 0):

The password is validating against the database, but the return value of `validate()` is undefined, when the email or password is wrong. This can result in unpredictable results. I recommend:

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));

    $query = $this->db->get('footable');

    return ($query->num_rows() == 1);
}
```

Comment: Same result as my code; email validates, any password (or no password) is accepted.

Comment: In ($query->num_rows == 1) the brackets are missing, it has to be ($query->num_rows() == 1)

Comment: I saw your update; tried the syntax you suggested w/num_rows() and I can still login with any or no password. The email is being validated but not the password.

Comment: What database are you using ? There are databases that don´t like sepcific fieldnames like "user" or "password". Maybe renaming the field helps. Does the field contain NULL? This can result in problems, too. Did you check the result of the $query? What does it contain?

Comment: Using mysql, fields don't contain null. Don't know how to check the $query, so advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This prints the result of a query:  print_r($query->result());